# GD library, text on image not working and errors

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to output text on an image and the page loads blank, with the following errors when setting error reporting on. Any idea why it's doing this and how I can resolve it?

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagecolorallocate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/gd-text/index.php on line 13
PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagettftext() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/gd-text/index.php on line 22
PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/gd-text/index.php on line 25
PHP message: PHP Warning:  imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/gd-text/index.php on line 28" while reading response header from upstream, client: 203.176.102.98, server: myserver.com, request: "GET /gd-text/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock:", host: "myserver.com"
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);

  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $black = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'myfont.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "Text on image test";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $black, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: Most probably wrong file path.

Comment: @Mikk as in the image and font are in the wrong path? They're both in the same dir as index.php...

Comment: your error indicates that variable $jpg_image equals to false, imagecreatefromjpeg returns false if a) file is not readable b) file doesn't contain image data known to GD library. Check for obvious problems - case sensitive file paths under most of unix system or maybe invalid file permissions.

Comment: Should it be using the `/var/www/...` path or relative path? Thanks @Mikk

Comment: both, relative and absolute paths should be ok. You can do var_dump(is_file('image.jpg') && is_readable('image.jpg')); to see whether file exists and is readable.

Answer (score 0):

..i'd think that the given path to your image doesnt work, since imagecreatefrom... returns boolean FALSE if no image could be created.
in any case it is saver to check things before handing them over to your process so you can interact with the excepteion / makes debbuging easyier...
see what you  get with your code if you do
 `<? ... var_dump(is_file($jpg)); ?>`